# Textview not scrolling inside custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I tried a lot for having scrolling text horizontally  inside a listview.
i want one of my textview to scroll horizontally automatically like marquee
iam able to set horizontal scroll bar and scroll on touching it as

```
TVad.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvinboxname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvinboxmsg"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvinboxname"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvtimeStamp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvinboxmsg"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvadmsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvtimeStamp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:lines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#330066" />
```

and in my getview method

```
    // @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inboxtextviews, null);
            Tvname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvinboxname);
            Tvname.setText(VCAESInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist.get(position)
                    .getname());
            TVmsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvinboxmsg);
            TVmsg.setText(VCAESInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist.get(position)
                    .getmessage());
            TVtimeStamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvtimeStamp);
            TVtimeStamp.setText(VCAESInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist.get(
                    position).getTimeStamp());

            TVad= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvadmsg);

            TVad.setText(VCAESInboxWithOutCheckboxes.Inboxlist.get(
                    position).getAd());

            TVad.setSelected(true);
);
            return convertView;
        }
```

i searched a lot on this in stackoverflow and not able to display the scrolling text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use custom class as shown below and

```
 public class MyTextView extends TextView{

 public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
        rotate();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
        rotate();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
        rotate();
    }

    private void rotate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setSelected(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {

        }
    }


  }
```

add it in xml file for custome listview like shown below

```
    <Your Package Name.MyTextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:id="@+id/tv_parse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="22px"
        android:textColor="#34A4c5"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxWidth="220dp" 
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"  
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></Your Package Name.MyTextView>
```

Comment: @Khan  will u please tell me wer do i place the above class MyTextView.Will  it be a inner class to Adapter class(Class that extends Baseadapter) and also the above xml file.I want my textfield which is present inside a listview row to be scrollable vertically.Please guide me on this. Thanks

Comment: @Joyson your wish where you want to put but i think put it globally so you are able to use in other class if required make simpleclass i think you know about it.

Comment: I have added the xml file to the customized listview xml file (where i define each row for listview).

Comment: how to scroll vertically ?

Answer (score 3):

It you want the TextView to scroll horizontally while list is IDLE you need to set the TextView to selected state.

```
public void bindView....
// Assuming you have a static view holder class

viewHolder.myTextViewToScroll.setSelected(true);
```

Now it should scroll :)

Comment: @ user1484117 it does not scroll. The textview is inside the row of the customized list view

Answer (score 0):

For this you design your list view row from XML using `SimpleListAdapter`.
Put a `scrollview` in a row in XML.

```
<LinearLayout>
<scrollView>
<textview/>
</scrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if we use scrollview it won't be scrolling as marquee. we have to scroll it. i want my text view to scroll automatically when my list view is opened