# How to make a TextView inside of custom ListView scrollable?

Tags: android

I have referred to the following URL:

[Textview not scrolling inside custom listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736422/textview-not-scrolling-inside-custom-listview)

but it's not working for me, where do I place the Java file and the XML file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this property in xml for custom row:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/descr" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="200dp" 
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.checking text "
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon" 
                android:layout_below="@id/subtitle"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/distance"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                />
```

Then set text in custom adaptor like this,

```
holder.des.setText(list.get(position).getSummary());
            holder.des.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

If the text is more then 3 line its scrolling.

Comment: Hi , Did this method conflict with list scrolling mechanism ?

Comment: Actually the above works however it is not user friendly while trying to scroll the text view the list view items get scrolled.